# Falied to resolve endpoint in apache camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am working on a spring mvc application and i am using apache camel to send message.When i run my code in test case it show to me error failed to resolve endpoint.It is my code:

```
  CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
    producerTemplate.requestBody(
            "jetty:http://here my message service http api",
            "hello", String.class);
```

Comment: Please provide more information about your error. Could you post your route?

Comment: It may be that you do not have camel-jetty on the classpath, add that to your maven pom.xml file or what build tool you use.

Answer (score 1):

When you see errors like "failed to resolve endpoint" in Camel, it's most likely due to lack of the dependency declaration in your Maven `pom.xml`. In your case, make sure your `pom.xml` has the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-jetty9</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```